# Is the HTTP Plugin supported in Real-time Google Data Fusion pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to create a really basic Real-time GDF pipeline where the source is an HTTP Property plugin that retrieves some info from an HTTP endpoint. However, whenever I do validate, I get this non-helpful "org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream" error.  Has anyone gotten a real-time source version of HTTP Property plugin to work in Data Fusion?

I made sure to fill in all required fields.  I also tested the endpoint through a different client, Postman, to make sure the endpoint itself is working.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP plugin has both batch source and streaming source :
https://github.com/data-integrations/http/tree/develop/src/main/java/io/cdap/plugin/http/source

could you attach the log of pipeline studio service and your pipeline json ?

Comment: Thank you.  I did a deployment of the POC and it does seem to have pulled the information successfully.  It did seem strange that during the Validate it fails without a useful error message.